# Transferring PHP class data on POST

Tags: php

Say I've got some class in PHP defined like so:

```
class foo
{
var $bar;
function foo($name)
{
$this->bar = $name;
}
}
```

Now let's assume I've created an instance of this class like so.

```
<form action="somenewform.php" method="POST">
<div name="somename">
<?PHP
$somevar = foo("someclassname");
?>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm relatively new to PHP and would just like to know how I'd go about retrieving that data on another page.  I understand you need to do $_POST['name'] to retrieve data, but how would I go about retrieving the value of bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer storing this sort of information in a session variable:

```
session_start();
$somevar = new foo( 'someclassname' );
$_SESSION['somevar'] = $somevar;
```

Then retrieve it on the next page:

```
session_start();
$somevar = $_SESSION['somevar'];
echo $somevar->bar;
```

You can read more on [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) on php.net.

Comment: Worked beautifully mate, thanks!

Edit:  And thank you for the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize the class, set it as a hidden input field, and then un-serialize it on the next page.

For example:

```
<form action="somenewform.php" method="POST">
<div name="somename">
<?php
$somevar = foo("someclassname");
?>
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo serialize($somevar); ?>" />
</div>
</form>
```

Then on your destination page un-serialize it

```
$somevar = unserialize($_POST['foo']);
echo $somevar->bar; //echos "someclassname"
```

Keep in mind that it is possible for the user to manipulate the data in the hidden input field and you should not trust that the data hasn't been tampered with. Make sure you check the data **BEFORE** you un-serialize it. If you need a more secure method consider using something like `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Although, unserializing without checking for sanity is a major security risk.

Comment: @GigaWatt Point taken, added a note about security.